# Check if all values are field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="answer_1">
          <input id="1" class="1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="2" class="2 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="3" class="3 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="4" class="4 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="5" class="5 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="6" class="6 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="7" class="7 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <button id="continue" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue">Weiter</button>
</div>
```

And values of this input is field dinamicly with JS on click on image (every input is field with click on other image). How can I check if all values are field (I tried with keyup function, but it is only work when manualy field inputs, not with JS, and if it is clicke, to do some css change (for example, when all inputs value are field, then change background of div)
Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean "filled" instead of "field"?

Comment: on continue click -> loop through all inputs -> if any .value is an empty string -> return false

Comment: When do you want to perform the check/validation? During `oninput`/`onchange`/`onkeyup` events on each input? During form submission? Or some other user-triggered event?

Comment: I want to check on every click on image that trigger filling vaules are all the fields are filled.

Answer (score 2):

You may use jquery as in the following example to execute javascript function to check filled elements. There are many approaches to this and this is one very simple of them.

```
<body>
<div class="answer_1">
          <input id="1" class="1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="2" class="2 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="3" class="3 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="4" class="4 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="5" class="5 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="6" class="6 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <input id="7" class="7 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
          <!--Added executing javascript function named check()-->
          <button id="continue" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue" onClick="check()">Weiter</button>
</div>


<script>
//function definition
function check(){

//loop through the inputs using their numbers
for(var i = 1; i<7; ++i){

//check if the value is filled
if ($('#' + i).val()){

//do anything you want, here I alert the element id which is the number
alert(i);

//or change css
$($('#' + i).addClass('example');
$($('#' + i).removeClass('anotherexample');
}
}}</script>

<!--jquery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Added some comments

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var isEmpty = false;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            var len = $.trim($(this).val()).length;
            if( len === 0)
                isEmpty = true;
        })

        if (!isEmpty)
            $('.answer_1').addClass('chn');
        else
            $('.answer_1').removeClass('chn');
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var isEmpty = false;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            var len = $.trim($(this).val()).length;
            if( len === 0)
                isEmpty = true;
        })

        if (!isEmpty)
            $('.answer_1').addClass('chn');
        else
            $('.answer_1').removeClass('chn');
    })
})
```

```css
.chn {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="answer_1">
    <input id="1" class="1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
    <input id="2" class="2 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
    <input id="3" class="3 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
    <input id="4" class="4 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
    <input id="5" class="5 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
    <input id="6" class="6 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
    <input id="7" class="7 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
    <button id="continue" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue">Weiter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The last lines lack some elegance, but at least the logic is right, unlike two of the other answers here. Up

Comment: For applying only space its perform as a filled

Comment: you can use `trim` for onlu space.

Comment: Is it just me, or do this snippet accept only one letter per input? I can only write one letter in each, what about you guys?

Comment: @JeremyThille ,  this is for all ,because `maxlength=1`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to check if inputs are filled using jquery.

```
var isAllFilled = 0;

$(".answer_1 > input").each(function()
    {
    if($(this).val()!="")
        {
        isAllFilled++;
        }

);

If(isAllFilled ==  $(".answer_1 > input").length)
{
//all fields are filled.
}
```

In you logic after this code ran check value of isAllFilled which tells you that whether all fields are filled or not.

Comment: Yurgh, this is inelegant as hell. Please. `$(".answer_1 > input").each( () => isAllFilled = !!$(this).val().length )`. Besides, it doesn't even work because it takes into consideration only the last element. `isAllFilled` will be set regardless of all but the last field. Downvoted

Comment: It is iterating all the elements , in the last if its value is false means there are one or more values which are'nt filled, If in last isAllFilled  is true then this means all fields are filled, Hope this help you to understand. Your views?

Comment: Fair enough, this might work, even though it's still not the best way IMO. Downvote removed :)

Answer (score 0):

add a `<form>` tag and `name` to each input

```
<form method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="validateForm()" action="">

 <div class="answer_1">
      <input id="1" class="1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" name="first"/>
      <input id="2" class="2 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" name="second"/>
       ...
       ...
      <button id="continue" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue">Weiter</button>
</div>

</form>



function validateForm()
{
    var a=document.forms["Form"]["first"].value;
    var b=document.forms["Form"]["second"].value;
    ....

    if (a==null || a=="" || b==null || b=="" ||...)
    {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could check if the value is empty or filled.

Just try to use the `.val()`-[function](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

```js
$(document).on("click", "#continue", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var emptyCounter = 0;

  $(".answer_1 > input").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      // Do something if it's empty or increase the counter
      console.log("Empty");
      emptyCounter = emptyCounter + 1;
    } else {
      // Do something if filled?
      console.log("Filled");
    }

  });

  if (emptyCounter == 0) {
    // submit?
    console.log("everything's good");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answer_1">
  <input id="1" class="1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
  <input id="2" class="2 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
  <input id="3" class="3 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
  <input id="4" class="4 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
  <input id="5" class="5 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
  <input id="6" class="6 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
  <input id="7" class="7 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
  <button id="continue" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue">Weiter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: use with [`trim()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilhfvk7tjVAhWIL48KHbQdAXIQFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Ftrim&usg=AFQjCNHplwP8uGVxgtKYMhsiv7EE8F9cMw) for unwanted empty space removing

Comment: Same problem as @amit's answer. It takes into consideration only the last element, regardless of all the previous ones. This can output `Empty Empty Filled Filled Empty Filled`, and will validate the form because the last one is filled. Downvoted

Comment: @JeremyThille Downvote because this example don't work like **you** expect it? Thank you. This is just an example to show him how he could do it. But I understand you and I changed it.

Comment: No, I downvoted because it wasn't working _at all_. Your validation was only taking into consideration the last field, not all of them. The logic was flawed, hence the downvote, accept it. Now you've made a code that works, I have removed my downvote.